Geotools checkCoordinatesRange() not throwing exception for certain CRS?
I am having trouble understanding how the function checkCoordinatesRange(Geometry, CoordinateReferenceSystem) works (Geotools to JTS). I was expecting it to throw an error when the coordinates are outside the bounds of the specified coordinate system.
When providing a projected CRS like EPSG:3067 or 2154, it never throws an error and when providing a geodetic CRS (like 4326 or 4618) it does throws an error if provided coordinates are outside the bounds.
When looking at the code of the function it looks like the minimal (and maximum value) is extracted using crs.getCoordinateSystem().getAxis(0).getMinimumValue() which is -Infinity for a EPSG:2154 and that doesn't match the bounds of the CRS (which can be found using CRS.getEnvelope(CoordinateReferenceSystem)).
I find it quite confusing, did I miss something?
Sample Code
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs_3067 = CRS.decode("EPSG:3067");
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs_4326 = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");

System.out.println(crs_3067.getCoordinateSystem().getAxis(0).getMinimumValue());
System.out.println(CRS.getEnvelope(crs_3067));

System.out.println(crs_4326.getCoordinateSystem().getAxis(0).getMinimumValue());
System.out.println(CRS.getEnvelope(crs_4326));

//No exception thrown
Point point = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(30000, 8000000));
JTS.checkCoordinatesRange(point, crs_3067);

//The exception is thrown
Point point2 = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(-100, 300));
//JTS.checkCoordinatesRange(point2, crs_4326);

Import
import org.geotools.api.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.geotools.api.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.PointOutsideEnvelopeException;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;


Certainly sounds like we need to improve the documentation, I would guess that the check is for mathematical safety rather than bounds checking the sensible area of use.
